# Doctrine one table to many tables and records

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I wonder can we make many relations between one table and many tables with many records in these tables?

For example;

I have a news table, that news can be mapped with Games, Developers, Platforms at the same time with multiple records.

Sample :

## News : Crysis 55 pre-order available

> Relations :
> {**Games**:Crysis 55; **Developers**:Crytek; **Platforms**:Ps3,Xbox360,Pc,Wii;}

I really could not imagine how to be orm design.

OneToMany, ManyToMany?

Waiting for your great helpings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ManyToMany will be the best fit for this. You could create 4 tables. One table for each (News, Games,Developers,Platforms). News will be your primary table that will contain foreign keys from games, developers, platforms.

This probably would help you in doctrine mapping.
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: we have a problem with your solution.. as you see, sometimes a news can have relation with multiple records in a table. so if i give an reference id it would be only 1 record for each table...

Comment: my mistake, you are right. ManyToMany would be best fit. Thank you.